# Crear trigger Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta sentencia para importar datos a la tabla prueba, lo que necesito es crear un trigger.

```
BULK
INSERT PRUEBA
FROM 'C:\prueba.CSV'
WITH
(
-- seteamos el separador de campos
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
--seteamos el separador de registro
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO
```

Comment: ¿Por qué querés hacerlo con un trigger?

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente trigger(de nombre NombreTrigger) se ejecutara después(AFTER) de cada insert en la tabla PRUEBA, donde puse el PRINT deberías codificar la función que quieres que realice el trigger, si necesitas más ayuda, amplia la info de la pregunta.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER NombreTrigger ON PRUEBA
    AFTER INSERT 
    AS
    PRINT 'Se inserto una fila';
```

EDIT: Como comenta el compañero @Lamak, deberas añadir el argumento FIRE_TRIGGERS a tu BULK INSERT

```
BULK
INSERT PRUEBA
FROM 'C:\prueba.CSV'
WITH
(
-- seteamos el separador de campos
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
--seteamos el separador de registro
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
FIRE_TRIGGERS
);
GO
```

Comment: De todas formas, para que un trigger se ejecute después de un `BULK INSERT`, este debe ser usar la opción `FIRE_TRIGGERS`. Como está en la pregunta, no se ejecutará el trigger